# Adding class to an element if it is out of viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working with a navigation dropdown and it has several dropdowns options. So I want to add a class `move-left` if it goes out of the viewport edge.

I have tried `getBoundingClientRect();` but it gives me following error :

> Uncaught TypeError: el.getBoundingClientRect is not a function

My browser is `chrome` latest version.

My code is:

```
var isElemInViewport = function(el){
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
      rect.top >= 0 &&
      rect.left >= 0 &&
      rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&     
      rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
}

var el = $('ul.nav-menu li ul li ul');
$('ul.nav-menu li ul li').hover(function(){
    if(!isElemInViewport(el)){
        alert('o ya')
    }
}, function(){
     if(!isElemInViewport(el)){
        alert('no more')
     }
})
```

Comment: Try `if(!isElemInViewport(this))`

Comment: No need to wrap a jQuery element again.

Comment: I wanted to suggest the opposite :-). Try `var el = $('ul.nav-menu li ul li ul')[0];`. `getBoundingClientRect` is a DOM function, and `el` gets a jQuery collection in your code.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to access a method that belongs to native DOM elements, through a jQuery object.

So, you need to change this line:

`var el = $('ul.nav-menu li ul li ul');`

To this:

```
// The jQuery object, at property '0', contains the native DOM element
// you want. If you were to get multiple matches for your selector,
// they'll be numbered in order: 
// $('selector')[0], $('selector')[1], $('selector')[2], ...

var el = $('ul.nav-menu li ul li ul')[0];
```